How can I define a custom pointer data type in Ghidra?
I have a Motorola 68K binary file that contains a table of a few hundred function pointers. If I set their data type to Pointer32, Ghidra interprets them as pointers as shown:
00100000 01 20 96 94     addr       DAT_01209694
00100004 01 20 96 b2     addr       DAT_012096b2
00100008 01 20 96 d0     addr       DAT_012096d0

However, while the function pointers are stored as 32-bit values, they use a unique segment/address scheme:

AA SA AA AA (the segment in this project is always 2 and needs to be ignored when parsing the pointer address)

Essentially, I need to make a 32-bit pointer data type that "ignores" the S part of the address, such that the data would look like this if it was correct:
00100000 01 20 96 94     addr       DAT_00109694
00100004 01 20 96 b2     addr       DAT_001096b2
00100008 01 20 96 d0     addr       DAT_001096d0

I'm somewhat new to Ghidra, so any pointers (pun intended) to where I can read up on creating custom pointer types would be greatly appreciated!

I can't tell you how to create a custom datatype for this off the top of my head[0], but if for your purposes it's sufficient for the address to show up correctly, and then the process should be the same as dealing with relative addresses as described here:

You can always set it manually to the specific address from the reference dialog (available under R). There you can providing the correct address calculated [...]. If you have more than one, you can automate it via python script.


I've recorded a video detailing such situation in action https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvH7b_qLmbU

[0] I think this would probably only matter if you want type propagation algorithms to handle this, e.g. if some struct will have a pointer of this type.
